# String not printing until key pressed in assembly BIOS

Tags: assembly, operating-system, nasm, bios

I am having a problem when writing my operating system in nasm assembly, and the problem is that, even though I am not calling the "keystroke" function, the body of the function seems to be executing, not matter what I do, and this is preventing me from printing out strings, until I press a key.

Code:
    BITS 16

```
;start of the os
start:
mov ax, 07C0h
add ax, 288
mov ss, ax
mov sp, 4096

mov ax, 07C0H
mov ds, ax
;-------------------


mov ah, 09h
mov cx, 1000h
mov al, 20h
mov bl, 1fh
int 10h

mov ah, 09h
mov cx, 80
mov al, 20h
mov bl, 70h
int 10h

;create mouse --

mov ah, 01h
mov cx, 07h
int 10h

mov bl, 34
mov cl, 0h
call _mouser

mov si, text_string
call print_string

mov bl, 0h
mov cl, 4h
call _mouser

mov si, clear_str
call print_string
mov si, start_str
call print_string

;call keystroke

jmp $

text_string db 'Zaphy OS v0.1', 0
clear_str db "", 0
start_str db "Press the Enter Key to use Zaphy OS", 0

_mouser:
mov ah, 02h
mov dl, bl
mov dh, cl
int 10h

keystroke:
mov ah, 00h
int 16h
cmp al, 13
je enterKey
jmp keystroke

enterKey:
;Working on it

print_string:
mov ah, 0Eh

.repeat
lodsb
cmp al, 0
je .done
int 10h
jmp .repeat

.done:
ret

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

Comment: Would that be because `_mouser` falls through into `keystroke` (which in turn falls through into `print_string`)? A "subroutine" that is called, needs to end with a `ret` instruction. Luckily, `print_string` has one.

Comment: Thank you so much @WeatherVane , this fixed it, and now I can continue development of the operating system!